# Why apt-get cannot install software?

Tags: installation, debian, package-management, apt-get

Each time I execute apt-get install  (e.g. gzip) I get the problems of kind:

```
Depends: <some_package> but is not going to be installed
Depends: <some_package> but is not installable
```

For each package I try to install!

What could be a problem?

Comment: Have you updated your repos (and upgraded the system)?  That's to be sure the system is seeing the updated package listings.  _$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade_

Comment: Take a look at this. They talk about it http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/debian-linux/69879-depends-ant-1-6-but-not-installable.html